# POST.has_key method error

Tags: python, django

When I don't fill out anythin in 'Title', I expect It shows me the message 'Fill out title. But It just shows me blank..

**views.py**

```
def add_post(request):
  entry_title = request.POST.get("title", False)
  if request.POST.has_key('title') == False:
    return HttpResponse('Fill out title')
  else:
    return HttpResponse('Hello %s' % entry_title)
```

**write.html**

```
<form method="post" action="/blog/add/post/">{% csrf_token %}
<p>
    <label for "title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="" />
</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `foo.has_key('bar')` should be spelled `'bar' in foo`.

Secondly, all you're doing is checking if there is a field called `title` in the form. Well, yes, of course there is, because you put it there yourself. What you should be checking is if that field has any actual content.

```
if not entry_title:
    return HttpResponse('Fill out title')
```